# Is there a way to capture changes on every DOM Element on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wrote this article quite a while back to "[Save Changes on Close of Browser or When Exiting the Page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20260/Save-Changes-on-Close-of-Browser-or-When-Exiting-t)". But I am thinking of approaching this in a better way using Javascript. Would someone be able to suggest me on how I could get to know or capture changes on every DOM Element of a page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents): "The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element."

Not sure how you would detect changes in DOM elements besides those listed above, but you can use the `onchange` event to keep track of elements that have been changed.

`element.onchange = function() { };`

Answer (score 0):

You can not listen to ALL events by default unless you subscribe to ALL events.

Even if you use a library, e.g. Prototype, you can do `document.on('DOMevent', callback)` but you have to specify which events you want to listen.